# order of execution of different components/actions in map-reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is the order of execution of the actions/components in map-reduce -
Mapper --> Combiner --> Shuffling/Sorting --> Partitioner --> Reducer

Is the order same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
The process is almost correct but let's clearly understand in depth of it.
First Map phase will start by running `map`.
Once `map` process the input, it will sort before it save in the local file system,
 which is called `sort` and then `copy` to the local file system and next this data will be copied to `reducer` which is `shuffle` phase.
Since the data is already sorted in each mapper output, it performs `merge sort` by each key coming to the reducer located node.
Once merge is done, the data is ready to enter the reduce phase. It depends on the manual configuration of your choice.
we can set number of reducers to zero as well. In that case all the output of `map` will be written directly to Output path either to local file system or hdfs as well.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much ,this explains the answer perfectly :)